# Notify Lightning Component when ApexBatch finishes

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, batch

What is the best way to notify the Lightning Component when ApexBatch (invoked by LC action method) finishes?

Use case - My LC is invoking ApexBatch to offload complex data processing. I want to let the user (still on the LC page), that the batch has completed, and they can now view the result.

I don't want to poll the server every X seconds to check batch job status, so looking for alternate approaches, which will minimize the # of API calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the Enterprise Messaging Platform is for. You place a [lightning:empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) in your component, and subscribe to listen to an event. Then, in your finish method, you use [EventBus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_eventbus.htm). You'll need to make sure that you have some sort of unique identifier (e.g. the Apex Batch job ID) so a client knows that their job is finished as opposed to any other job that might be running on the same channel. Make sure you unsubscribe when you're done listening.

Note: round trips to the server don't actually "cost" API calls. They're free to use as frequently as you'd like, including polling the server for updates. Granted, using EMP is still the preferred method, whenever possible, but API costs should not be a concern for normal applications and components.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**LWC** can also catch Platform events sent by a Batcheable:

See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) for an example of subscribing a LWC to Platform events

Publishing your event can be done in the *finish* method of a batch:

```
EventBus.publish(someEvent);
```

if you need to pass batcheable job's id to the platform event - it is is available using the `BC.getJobId()` of the method `finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}` [See docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm)

This way you can compare the Id with the Id you got when the batch job was called - verifying the event was fired for the same job.

It's useful to add more custom fields to your platform event to pass any status/result information from a batch job to your LWC.